# two layouts in one fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem using two different layouts (two `.xml` files) in one `Fragment`.
For example, I have `layout1.xml` and `layout2.xml`. `layout1.xml` has the `Button` 'next', and if user clicks this `Button` in `layout1`, `layout1` should disappear and `layout2` should appear. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use one fragment, make each layout associated with one fragment. So two layouts, two fragments. The next button will then call back the the parent activity that handles the fragments and that will put the current one on the back stack and create the new fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong approach. Either combine these two layouts in one and use i.e. `ViewFlipoer` or put them into overlaying `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` and show/hide the one you need. Or split your logic into two fragments

Comment: this is what I wrote. `<include> combines layouts in one.

Comment: I'm saying you don't have to "combine these two layouts in one", you can reference them both, using their current xmls, rather than copy and paste them into a single xml. Just vernacular, was adding another way to do it.

Comment: I did not say to "combine two files", "but two layouts". So one can use `<include>`, other can put it one file. Whatever serves you best. Valid comment though, as many are unaware of `<include>`

Comment: Ok, so I did like you had written - I used <include> tag, within `Relative Layout`, and now it almost works as I wanted, except that: if I click `next Button`, layout changes and I only see `layout2`, but I want to go back to `layout1` using back button on my device. Now back button just leave whole fragment. How can I achieve that back button would go back to `layout1`?

Comment: then I'd suggest to use Fragments for this as there's backstack. If you do not want to, override `onBackPressed()` and handle this case yourself